# Need Help identify ICs in battery protector PCB

Tags: batteries, circuit-protection

Does anyone recognize these ICs? Manufacturer, model # etc. They are part of a lithium-ion battery protector.
Many thanks for your help

(I added the silkscreen, traces, and edited the pictures so it shows the IC numbers of other components) 3 and 4 appear in the same place but different boards

[image: unknown battery ic]

Comment: Numbers 3 through 6 all appear to have the Microchip logo on them, if that helps.

Comment: Looks like the Microchip IC's only contain YWW (year code (last digit) and week code) and NNN (Alphanumeric traceability code). You could try contacting Microchip requesting information on these alphanumeric traceability code.

Comment: Adding pictures of the silkscreen (white text) may also help identifying, as well as surrounding components and traces.

Answer (score 3):

1. A search on "QFW SOT23-5" came up with the LM3620M5 battery controller as the best bet.
2. "KD0J4 SOT23" returned nothing directly. Shortening down to KD returned a link to http://www.smdmark.com/en-US/smd-code-KD.html which in combination with the package type (SOT23) returned the DZ23C8V2, 8.2V Zener diode. Not 100% sure on this, but it seems likely for the application.
3. Cannot get anything on these solely based on package markings. They may be obsolete, in which case I wonder if I have a databook at home. Will update if I find anything.